# Loud whining noise coming from gearbox when in 5th gear

Tags: noise, nissan, manual-transmission, gears

A little while ago my gear box started to make a loud whining noise when I accelerate in 5th gear, so mainly on the highway. It also happens in 4th but is a lot more subtle than in 5th gear.

It almost sounds like a similar noise to straight cut gears. Obviously not that similar but there is a resemblance with how it whines.

It only happens when accelerating, even just a tiny bit makes the noise. It also gets louder the quicker the engine/gear box is spinning. As soon as I take my foot off the accelerator it stops, so doesn't make the noise when coasting in 5th.

The car is a 1998 Nissan Pulsar N15.

I can make an edit with a video of the noise soon.

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 2):

I had my 2002 Jeep Wrangler sounding like it had straight cut gears just a bit ago.  I changed the gear oil and it's now quiet again.  I went ahead and changed the front and rear diffs and transfer case while I was at it too since they were all overdue.  It's amazing how loud gears can be with old gear oil.